# Create new column with information of another column if two elements of row are equal

Tags: r, multiple-columns

Im very new to R and did not find a solution to my specific problem. I really hope you guys can help me.

I have the following data frame:

```
hid <- c('1','2','2','2','2','4','4','4','4','4','4')
syear <- c(2000,2001,2003,2003,2003,2000,2000,2001,2001,2002,2002)
employlvl <- c('Full-time','Part-time','Part-time','Unemployed','Unemployed','Full-time','Full-time','Full-time','Unemployed','Part-time', 'Full-time')
relHead <- c('Head','Head','Head','Partner','Child','Head','Partner','Head','Partner','Head','Partner')

df <- data.frame(hid,syear,employlvl,relHead)



| hid | syear |  Employment | Relation to Head of HH|
|-----|-------|-------------|-----------------------|
|  1  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2001  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2003  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |         Child         |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |
|  4  | 2001  |  Full-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2001  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |
|  4  | 2002  |  Part-time  |         Head          |
|  4  | 2002  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |
```

I would like to create a new column with the employment level of the Partner if the values in hid (household identification number) and syear (survey year) are equal.

I hope to get the following output:

```
| hid | syear |  Employment | Relation to Head of HH| Employment Partner|
|-----|-------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
|  1  | 2000  |  Part-time  |         Head          |        NA         |
|  2  | 2001  |  Part-time  |         Head          |        NA         |
|  2  | 2003  |  Part-time  |         Head          |    Unemployed     |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |       Partner         |        NA         |
|  2  | 2003  |  Unemployed |         Child         |        NA         |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |         Head          |     Full-time     |
|  4  | 2000  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |        NA         |
|  4  | 2001  |  Full-time  |         Head          |    Unemployed     |
|  4  | 2001  |  Unemployed |        Partner        |        NA         |
|  4  | 2002  |  Part-time  |         Head          |     Full-time     |
|  4  | 2002  |  Full-time  |        Partner        |        NA         |
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also what do you mean *if the values in hid (household identification number) and syear (survey year) are equal.*?

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick response. By equal I mean that the new column should only consider those rows with matching hid and syear. I also added the code for the data frame. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could achieve this by using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. There are two steps.

Step 1: Find out which `hid` and `syear` combinations have more than two records. Filter them and also filter out the records with `Child`. Use `spread` to find the `Head` and `Partner` relationship, creating a new data frame. Create a new column with `Head` for merging. `dt2` is the output of this step.

Step 2: Use `left_join` to combine `dt2` with the original data frame `dt`. `dt3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(hid, syear) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  filter(`Relation to Head of HH` != "Child") %>%
  spread(`Relation to Head of HH`, Employment) %>%
  mutate(Relation = "Head") %>%
  rename(`Employment Partner` = Partner) %>%
  select(-Head)

dt3 <- dt %>%
  left_join(dt2, by = c("hid", "syear", "Relation to Head of HH" = "Relation"))
```

Data:

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- data_frame(hid = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                 syear = c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002),
                 Employment = c("Full-time", "Part-time", "Part-time", "Unemployed", "Unemployed",
                                "Full-time", "Full-time", "Full-time", "Unemployed", "Part-time", 
                                "Full-time"),
                 "Relation to Head of HH" = c("Head", "Head", "Head", "Partner", "Child", "Head", 
                                              "Partner", "Head", "Partner", "Head", "Partner"))
```

Comment: I am glad it helps! Please accept my answe if it is useful.

Comment: Just one more question. When I try to run the code on my data I get the following Error: Data source must be a dictionary. Do you maybe know what the problem is?

Comment: I am not familiar with this error. My google search of this error leads me to some pages talking about issues associated with the `rlang` package. Maybe it would be helpful to re-installed the `dplyr` package or even install the `tidyverse` package to keep things up to date. If you still cannot fix this, maybe you can try to create a new post to talk about this. error

Comment: Thanks for your advice I will definitely create a new post. I think the problem might be that I have more columns than in the data set above. If I add another column in the small example dataframe I don't get the output I was hoping for. Do you know how to treat other columns to get the desired output?